# customize iTerm2 background pane color

Tags: zsh, oh-my-zsh, iterm2

using iTerm2 on mac with oh-my-zsh.

looking at the pref > profile > colors, I don't see a way to customize these:

[image]

it seems like an opacity or some darkening hsl or something, how can I tweak that?

Comment: Preferences > Appearance > Dimming

Comment: post as answer and I'll accept it

Comment: This question was off-topic for Stack Overflow; it should have been posted on apple.stackexchange.com.

Answer (score 1):

You can only adjust the [dimming](https://iterm2.com/documentation-preferences-appearance.html).

`Preferences` `Appearance` `Dimming` `Dimming amount`